# java hashing objects

Tags: java, hash, reference, cycle

I'd like to be able to determine whether I've encountered an object before - I have a graph implementation and I want to see if I've created a cycle, probably by iterating through the Node objects with a tortoise/hare floyd algorithm.

But I want to avoid a linear search through my list of "seen" nodes each time. This would be great if I had a hash table for just keys. Can I somehow hash an object? Aren't java objects just references to places in memory anyway? I wonder how much of a problem collisions would be if so..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is to create a `HashSet` and add each node to the set the first time you encounter it.

The only case that this won't work is if you've overloaded `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` for the node class to implement equality based on node contents (or whatever).  Then you'll need to:

- use the `IdentityHashMap` class which uses `==` and `System.identityHashcode` rather than `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`, or
- build a hashtable yourself using your own flavour of object identity.

---

> Aren't java objects just references to places in memory anyway?

Yes and no.  Yes, the reference is represented by a memory address (on most JVMs).  The problem is that 1) you can't get hold of the address, and 2) it can change when the GC relocates the object.  This means that you can't use the object address as a hashcode.

The `identityHashCode` method deals this by returning a value that is *initially* based on the memory address.  If you then call `identityHashCode` again for the same object, you are guaranteed to get the same value as before ... even if the object has been relocated.

> I wonder how much of a problem collisions would be if so..

The hash values produced by the `identityHashCode` method can collide.  (That is, two distinct objects *can* have the same identity hashcode value.)  Anything that uses these values has to deal with this.  (The standard `HashSet` and `IdentityHashMap` classes take care of these collisions ... if you chose to use them.)

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to be able to determine whether I've encountered an object
>   before

Use an [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). It is the ideal for your job since it is not an `equals` but a `==` implementation.

Comment: The reference is dead :-(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Note that in order for objects to work with HashSet, they need to provide correct implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the `java.lang.Object` class.

Comment: It's likely that the default implementations of hashCode() and equals(), which have identity semantics, will be sufficient for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement a hash function for your objects. This is done by overriding `hashCode()` defined in `java.lang.Object`. This method is used by `HashMap`, `HashSet` etc to store objects. In `hashCode()` it's up to you to calculate a hash for the object. Don't forget to also implement the `equals()`-method!

Take a look at Java collection framework (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading: there is a built-in hashCode() that provides identity semantics.

Comment: Thank you @kdgregory. First sentence removed.